# WCF initialization using Bootstrapper for Unity and Automapper

Tags: wcf, bootstrapper

I am using Unity Container and Automapper and I'm looking for a place to call my initialization and bootstrapping code in my WCF Service. My internet searches have recommended one of four approaches as discussed here
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2006/01/11/511514.aspx

```
(e.g. 
1. Global.asax, 
2. App_Code\AppInitialize, 
3. custom ServiceHost, and 
4. ServiceHostBase.InitializeRuntime)
```

However, I was also wondering if anyone has used the "Bootstrapper" project
http://bootstrapper.codeplex.com/
with the Unity and Automapper extensions.

So where/how is the best place to call the "Bootstrapper.Run()" code in a WCF Service? Sample code would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hey Raymond, did you ever get this figured out? I'm looking for the same type of answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use web activator and call initialize method on your bootstrapper class. see details on https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebActivatorEx/